# Create the empty structure with the LLVM C++ API

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

How can the empty structure be created using the LLVM C++ API?

In the LLVM IR I would just write `{} {}`.

It can be used for instance in a return statement: `ret {} {}`?